# A sql statement, how to copy values in 1 column to another column in that same table

Tags: sql

Sample:
There is a table with 3 columns, c1, c2 and c3.

```
- c1 is the PK. 
- c2 is empty.
- c3 is same data type as c2 and empty.
```

How to write a sql statement to copy values in c3 to c2 for all rows accordingly?

Comment: If both `c3`and `c2`are empty, what's the point of copying between them? Anyway, you want an update statement as suggested by @TechDo

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET C2=C3
```